# How to access Sinatra's helpers from within models?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

A few of the methods on my models need to have access to the currently active user. In routes and views, this is handled by a helper method I wrote, but I have no idea how I'd find out who's logged in from the model.

EDIT: Here's my specific use case, for context.

I'm writing a forum using Sinatra and Sequel. The `ForumThread` model has a `.search(query_string)` method that decomposes a string and does fulltext search, as well as filtering by tag and state of the threads. In particular, the thread state require access to the currently active user in order to determine whether a thread has new content, for example.

I'm not a fan of having to do `ForumThread.search("something", current_user)`, but I don't like allowing the model to "magically" access the router either.

Comment: The model should not have access to this. If it needs this access then the variable should be passed to it such as `Acticle.by_user(@current_user)` where `by_user` is a scope that accepts a `User` as an argument.

Comment: I agree, and that's exactly what I've been doing, but I feel that it would be cleaner if some methods could just "find out" about the user behind the scenes instead of relying on it being a method parameter.

Comment: I can understand the temptation but I do not see this as a proper design concept. This type of logic should be handled in the controller and the Model should be left to handle it's own logic accordingly. I you really want to do this you should simply `require` the helper in the model file. e.g. `require 'user_helper'` or I believe you can call the methods by their full name e.g. `UserHelper::current_user` without the need to `require`.

Comment: Updated the question with more information about my specific scenario.

Comment: okay so why not add a method to `User` to handle this e.g. `current_user.search_forums("something")` then the `User` model will know it's own instance an perform a search of `Forum` from there.

Comment: I completely agree with @engineersmnky, if you really need this then wrap the forum search in a convenience method for the current user instance, otherwise, use the alternatives given.